# Testing stuff in Age of Empires II HD

Tags: age-of-empires-ii-hd

I am trying to get a foot back into AoE 2 after not having played it for 15 years. I would like to get a gut feeling for how well different units do against one another and how powerful upgrades are and so on. Maybe even practice some beginner level micro. As such, I would like some quick and consistent way to generate units and buildings, select or deselect different upgrades for each of the two armies, and then pit them against one another.

What is the easiest framework for doing something like this? I am at the moment running AoE2 HD on Steam.

Comment: FoxMcCloud is right, but... Search youtube for "Spirit of the law". His channel is dedicated to doing tests like the ones you want to do.

Comment: @Roflo I know about SotL. And I have seen a few of his vids. But they are, ultimately, limited to what he has had the time to set up and research (for instance, I don't think he has videos answering all possible "how many of this ranged unit with these upgrades does it take to one-shot one of these units, with these upgrades?", which is one of the things I would like to figure out, since that seems like an essential constant to have in mind). That is basically exactly what I'm after, though: not his videos, but how he sets them up. Or, at least, _some_ reasonable way of setting up such things.

Comment: Ah, I see. Well, AFAIK there's no easy way around custom scenarios for each _test_.

Comment: Anyone know why my comment (saying that you could use the Scenario editor) was deleted? Just curious.

Comment: @Joachim No idea. But I did read it, and I tested, and while it's not optimal (seemingly can't place down archers in imperial age, or militia in castle/imp, as they get automatically upgraded, and the lists of units, upgrades etc are a bit long with no filtering or sorting options, for instance), it is decent and will fill my needs for the time being.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is impossible unless you create a custom Scenario for each of the things you are describing. A sandbox map doesn't exist. Your best bet is to play against an easy AI or battle a friend and have them build units against you.

Comment: Custom scenarios seems to fit the bill somewhat. An easy AI won't let me test anything other than what he throws at me, and I don't have easy access to friends. It's slightly cumbersome, and I will have to fiddle with it for now. But it fits my needs decently.